# event firing but not being handled by the component

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have the following code within one of the components on my lightning component (salesforce) app:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="openSidebarEvent" type="c:OpenSidebarEvent" />
```

The Component event looks as below:

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template">
    <aura:attribute name="postId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="type" type="String" />
</aura:event>
```

and this is how I am firing the event from same compoent:

```
var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:openSidebarEvent");
        appEvent.setParams({ postId: selected_feedId });
        appEvent.setParams({ type: "post" });
        appEvent.fire();
```

Now the receiver component has this:

```
<aura:handler event="c:OpenSidebarEvent" action="{!c.highlightPost}" />

 highlightPost: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("application event handle");
  }
```

So basically highlightPost() is never called on this component.

But I do have exactly same thing in another component and it works there. Not entirely sure why would this not work on this component? Does the hierarchy of cmps matter?

Comment: Hierarchy does not matter with application events. Can you post your handler code?

Comment: this is the handler method: console.log("application event handled"); and <aura:handler event="c:OpenSidebarEvent" action="{!c.highlightPost}" />

Comment: Can you modify your question with the full formatted controller code?

Comment: sure i will do it

Comment: @Programmatic i updated my question

Comment: The only thing I notice that could be causing a problem is the documentation has the json properties as a string, but I'm doubtful thats the issue. Can you try these 2 things? First wrap postId and type with quotes so its "postId": selected_feedId and "type": "post". And second wrap your controller method that fires your event with a try catch and console log the error if there is one. Sometimes syntax/logic errors are not shown in the console

Comment: @Programmatic I tried both, giving explicitely a 'value' as string also added try catch, nothing seem to change

Comment: Ok one more thing, is that your `registerEvent` and `handler` have `c:OpenSidebarEvent` with a capital `O`, however your `$A.get(e.c:openSidebarEvent);` is lowercase. Again I'm not positive that will fix this issue but it's worth a shot

Comment: @Programmatic still not working! This is so weird! Makes me hate salesforce

Comment: There must be a syntax issue in another component, or the component that handles your event is not rendered and therefore cannot handle it. I would take this question over to salesforce.stackexchange.com. It will get more eyes there

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Application Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application.htm),

> The framework supports capture, bubble, and default phases for the propagation of application events.

That means that in order to receive a signal from a fired event, it should have a common component (disregarding hierarchy).

Just like in this [Application Event Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_example.htm), it shows at the bottom that they have a common point of contact (both are enclosed in a single lightning app) for the default phase to handle the event via the platform's original handling behavior.

I suggest having a common parent component and declare the notifier event there.

[image]